# Regular expression to remove spaces between boundaries

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string of this form:

```
101 E 11th St #201 B, Austin, TX 78702
```

I want to remove any white space between the pound sign and the first comma, so the string will become this:

```
101 E 11th St #201B, Austin, TX 78701
```

I know how to do a string replace in Ruby, but I don't know the regex to match only spaces between those two characters.

Comment: Ruby.  I know the command to replace a string, I just don't know how to match only certain characters between two boundaries.

Comment: A comma after `TX` is gone. Is that intended?

Comment: Shouldn't have been in the first string.  Fixt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a callback to do this ...

```
s = '101 E 11th St #2 01   B, Austin, TX 78702'
s.sub(/#[^,]+/) {|m| m.gsub(/\s/, '')}
# => "101 E 11th St #201B, Austin, TX 78702"
```

Comment: Yep, that works.  If anyone else has other solutions, I'll check them too.